# Questions which are too simple: is this one reasonable?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

[Stack Overflow: in java what is the syntax for commenting out multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449304/in-java-what-is-the-syntax-for-commenting-out-multiple-lines)

I understand that we're okay with people asking easily Googleable questions on SO. I normally overlook easy or lazy questions since one of SO's goals is to become a repository of answers to common beginners' questions. I get that, and it's a great goal. But isn't this taking it a bit too far? I don't mean to be snarky but I can't imagine this question helping anybody.

I didn't write anything on SO itself 'cause if the community deems this a fair question I don't want to crap in the thread, so to speak.

Answer (score 16):

If it's not a duplicate, I'd let it be.

It generates content at least, and someone searching google in the future may find the stackoverflow result and come to the site

Comment: content is king!

Comment: @CrazyJugglerDrummer: Hell no! Good content is king!

Answer (score 5):

If the goal of the SO sites is to be a repository of knowledge, then there is no choice but to include the simplest of the simple questions as well.

The voting usually determines what is valuable to the community, and somewhat unsurprisingly, that question garnered a net 0 vote (gained reputation aside).

Comment: But gained reputation is a lot more important than net vote

Comment: @DVK: The truth is that that question really shouldn't have gotten *any* votes, up or down. It's a necessary question, but it has little value to the community. The net vote is more important than rep because the amount of rep gained or lost by a post is subject to change later on, as the coming global rep recalc *will do* to that post.

Answer (score 1):

I don't mind a question that's really basic.  I try to approach it this way.  Apologies for the cliché, but it's not always about giving a man a fish, it's also about teaching them to fish - that is, finding answers for themselves.  So I might answer the question and also take the opportunity to show them how to Google or use other tools to discover the answer for themselves.  Some people get pissy and put the person down, but that's not necessary and only hints at self-esteem issues. :)

Comment: Please do not "take the opportunity to show them how to Google" in an answer.

Answer (score -9):

The question is completely legitimate.  But I usually downvote such questions.

Comment: Those two sentences would seem to be mutually exclusive. I normally downvote such answers, but I'm in a good mood this evening.

Comment: What's a *good mood*, @Neil?

Comment: -1. Because it's a beginner/noob/basic question is no reason to downvote it. If it's a _crap_ beginner/noob/basic quesion (as in subjective, not-a-real-question etc), then go nuts with the down votes ; )

Comment: @David, I think that asking how to do multiline comments *is* a crap question, let alone beginner's.  Perhaps you have another criteria--all people are different, you know?

Comment: @Neil, there are other means to remove non-legitimate questions: flagging, voting to close.  -1 to question stands for different thing.